# How to add a timer to a Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking at a cooldown to a function I've created so that once the function has been ran and the "else' tag has been ran that it wouldn't attempt to run again for 15 minutes.

Is there a simple way of doing this. My code is below and I've inserted a add here section for where I would want it to run.

```
function Cancel() {
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  // first prompt
  var presult = ui.prompt(
    "Please Enter the Password!",
    ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  var password = "Money2022";
  var pbutton = presult.getSelectedButton();
  var ptext = presult.getResponseText();

  // User clicked "OK" on first prompt
  if (pbutton == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
    ui.alert('Wrong Answer Buddy!');
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('2022').hideSheet();
    } else if (pbutton == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
      ui.alert('Wrong Answer Buddy!');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('2022').hideSheet();
    } else if (ptext != password) {
      Password();   
    } else {
      **!!INSERT FUNCTION HERE!!**

    }
  }

function Password() {
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.alert("Wrong Answer Buddy!",
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  if (response == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
    ui.alert("BYE BYE!");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('2022').hideSheet();
  } else if (response == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
    ui.alert("BYE BYE!");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('2022').hideSheet();
  } else {
    Cancel();
  }
}
```

Comment: Utilities.sleep()

Comment: The question looks to need some work to be clear. By one hand it might be helpful if you describe what  your script should do and assign a name to all the states (i.e. you might use idle, busy and cooldown). What is the main function and how it's called / triggered? Assuming that you have a button or custom menu that might be clicked by a spreadsheet editor at any time, what do you want to happen when someone try to run the function when the script state is "cooldown"? Are you using a consumer (free / gmail.com) account or a Workspace account?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Cooper's suggestion of using `Utilities.sleep()` already worked for you but I'd like to add a little more information and another way to do this for anyone else with a similar question.

Since you mentioned that you wanted to cooldown for 15 minutes you should know that the maximum sleep time for `Utilities.sleep()` is 300000 milliseconds or 5 minutes. You can find this documented [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleep(Integer)).

As an alternative to bypass this limit you can consider using the [Properties service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties). This allows you to save properties for either the users or the entire script, so you can set a property with a time *x* minutes from now and the script can check if it's passed this time before running. This allows you to set the cooldown as long as you want, and choose between having different cooldowns for each user or lock the entire document.

Here's an example of how you could do it:

```
function yourProcess(){

  var properties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties() //gets all properties
  var cooldownprop = properties.getProperty("cooldown") //gets cooldown property
  var now = new Date()
 
  //if cooldown has not been set it just sets the current time so the user can go through
  var cooldown = cooldownprop == null ? now : new Date(cooldownprop)
    
  if (now >= cooldown){
    //run your code
    
    //this sets the cooldown if needed, add the time in milliseconds
    properties.setProperty("cooldown", new Date(now.getTime()+900000))
  } else {
    //tell the user they're on cooldown
  }
}
```

For more information and samples on how to use the properties you can check out the documentation.

##### Sources:

- [Utilities.sleep()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleep(Integer))
- [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties)

Comment: I don't think that Utilities.sleep() will be helpful in this case, as it doesn't prevent other executions to run... perhaps the Lock service might be helpful but only if the OP is using a Google Workspace account.